# Pomelo JSON columns do not track changes?

Tags: entity-framework-core, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

Question time people!

I am trying to implement a JSON column with Pomelo and it worked like a charm until I realized it did not work with the `EF`'s change detection.

The entities look like this.

```
public class Child
{
    public string name {get;set;}
}
public class Entity
{
    public List<Child> Children {get;set;}
}
```

The `dbcontext` maps the `Entity` to a json column.

```
entity.Property(e => e.Children)
                .HasColumnType("json")
```

Adding a new `Entity` works and so does retrieving an `Entity`. The json gets converted to and from the `list` very nicely.

But when you add an element to the `Children` list and call `SaveChanges()`, EF acts as if they do not know of any changes! However, if you explicitly call `dbContext.Update(entity)` and shove the entity down EF's throat, then it updates.

Any idea why this happens?

I found [this bug](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/1140) which reports a similar scenario but it has since been fixed.

Comment: Check this pat [Overriding the default comparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-comparers?tabs=ef5#overriding-the-default-comparer). IOW, you need to redefine value comparer for this property.

Answer (score 0):

@Svyatoslav thank you for the suggestion. The link you had provided was very helpful.

As it turns out, there is a neat little option that we can use so that `EF` will actually bother enough to track the changes of a `JSON` column.

One can either set this option globally or per property. I could not get the global settings to work, however the property level settings did it for me!

```
entity.Property(e => e.Children)
.HasColumnType("json")
.HasColumnName("Children")
 // tell EF how to track the changes
.UseJsonChangeTrackingOptions(
    MySqlCommonJsonChangeTrackingOptions.FullHierarchySemantically
 );
```